# Is it possible to have an upColor on a Area graph using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a Area chart that would like to know if it's possible to have an upcolor for when it goes up. The upColor option works in the waterfall, candlestick charts. What about area charts anyone has an idea if it's possible? Below is a snippet of my series.

```
series: [ {
        upColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        data: AreaData,
        type: 'area',
        name: 'NAV',
        id: 'GG'
           
        }
    ], 



 [1483074000000, 529565.95]
 [1485838800000, 581409.01]
 [1488258000000, 635260.08]
 [1490932800000, 664102.35]
 [1493352000000, 638819.73]
 [1493524800000, 638819.73]
 [1494475200000, 638911]
 [1494561600000, 689111.15]
 [1494820800000, 717497.05]
 [1494907200000, 720143.97]
[1494993600000, 724890.17]
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your requirement well - would you like to have a visual output as is rendered in the shared demo? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gx7ec0sp/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ibra96/mjkrLw90/1/  I want green color when its up and red when its down

Comment: I see, but could you provide more info? Your data will be static or dynamic? Could you share a sample of your data? And you haven't answered my previous question - `would you like to have a visual output as is rendered in the shared demo`.

Comment: It will be great to have the output as rendered in the ex. Data will be stored in a React component state. " If value is more than the start value green color and red else"

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data which will be used? It will be much easier to find a solution for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - the area series doesn't have implemented the upColor feature to change the color of the increasing data. What can be done in this case is to use the `zones` feature to fill particular parts of the area.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/73pm4awq/

```
events: {
  load() {
    const chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      points = series.points,
      zones = [];

    series.points.forEach((p, i) => {
      if (points[i + 1] && p.y < points[i + 1].y) {
        zones.push({
          value: points[i + 1].x,
          color: 'green'
        })
      } else {
        zones.push({
          value: p.x,
          color: 'red'
        })
      }
    });
    series.update({
      zones: zones
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Sebastian's response to compare every point to the first point in the series. "Since Inception"

```
    events: {
  load() {
    const chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      points = series.points,
      zones = [];

    series.points.forEach((p, i) => {
      if ( points[0].y < points[i].y ) {
        zones.push({
          value: points[i].x,
          color: 'green'
        })
      } else {
        
        zones.push({
          value: p.x,
          color: 'red'
        })
      }
    });
    series.update({
      zones: zones
    })
  }
}
```

In addition to the zoneAxis property **series.zoneAxis** which "Defines the Axis on which the zones are applied." according to the docs.

```
zoneAxis:'x'
```